# Technique for localizing a web site

Tags: php, html, mysql, localization

I'm working on a home made website that runs on my own server at home. Nothing really big. But I now want to make it beta so some friends of mine could try its functionalities and help me improve them.

Some of them do not speak French however so I have to localize the site. I found some answers, like how to effectively chose the language to use (browser default, etc.). The best practices to have a good translation, etc. but I wonder what may be a good design to localize the site, technically speaking.

I mean should I store the strings into my mysql database and fetch them?
Into files?

Or is there some apache2 plugin that features the right tools?

Or something else I don't even have an idea of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term you're looking for is *internationalization*, and there are many libraries in a variety of languages that handle this problem.

[Here](https://github.com/tomzx/php-i18n) is an adaptation of `i18n`, a Ruby internationalization library converted into php.

You can store translation strings in-memory in php for smaller sites, or in a database for larger ones and fetch them dynamically at runtime. There are obvious performance drawbacks to the latter, but for a large enough site, you may have no choice.

Comment: That is perhaps why I didn't find what I was looking for :) My site is really small, so using files may be largely enough. I'll take i118 as a base then.

Comment: Good luck! And good for you for making your site accessible :)